# Parse BMD file format structure

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reverse-engineering, file-format

Firstly and most important, I would like to clarify that doesn't exists any kind of malicious intentions on this question, the purpose of all this is to work on a language translation of the words and phrases contained in a file format, simply as that.

And secondly, I'm looking for whatever kind of help, like just a explanation that could help me to continue, or maybe a C# or VB.NET code that illustrates the way to acchieve this issue.

---

The file that I'm working on this question, is this:

- http://www.mediafire.com/file/ij7ei668hzw60w7/datBootsHelp.bmd

Its filename is **datBootsHelp.bmd**, its file format is **BMD**, which is privative, however, exists information on some *wikis*.

The **BMD** file format contains two tables after the header, I need to programaticaly parse then represent the information stored in the second table, to be able export it to a plain text-file with a human-readable syntax then translate the exported text.

This is an example of the table I mean (partially):
[image]

In the next image below, I'll show the known specifications for this file format, and additional commentaries of mine with the progress I did and the values that I obtained analyzing the **datBootsHelp.bmd** that I shared at the beginning of this thread.

[image]

The rows marked with a green sign are the values that I managed to locate and to parse programmatically without problems, the rows with a red cross are the ones that have not yet, and the row with a question mark is the offset which is causing me problems and so it prevents me from working proper with the values of the red cross...

The problem I have is that I can not determine in which offset is delimited the end of first table, with the start of the second table, nor do I understand which is the exact length (counting the zeros/null bytes, it is understood) of the fields/texts of the second table, that is, I can not understand where the text identifier begins, what is their length/text-capacity, and where the text description begins and what is their length/text-capacity.

If I manualy analyze and compare each field per individual to try to figure out the fixed length of the fields, it gives me different lengths so I do not squat anything... but that just means that I'm analyzing it wrong, because it must have a maximum length, of course.

Supposedly and to my understanding, the first table ends at offset **814** (**0x32C**) as mentioned in the image above. In this image below I made a selection starting from that offset until I find the beginning of the first letter of the first text identifier... and there are 2 bytes in middle (**A4 1D**) that I do not know what they are but I think are "unused" for this purpose:

[image]

---

Finally, and if helpful, here I'll share the essential part of the source-code written in VB.NET on which I developed the algorithm to read the header data and to parse the first table.

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Represents the BMD File Format.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <remarks>
''' <see href="http://datacrystal.romhacking.net/wiki/Persona_3_and_4/BMD_%28File_Format%29"/>
''' </remarks>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public NotInheritable Class BMDFormat

#Region " Private Fields "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specifies the offset where the header begins.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly HeaderOffset As Integer = &H0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specifies the offset where the non-text table begins. This is the first table in the BMD file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly TableNonTextOffset As Integer = &H24

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specifies the offset where the text table begins. This is the second table in the BMD file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Private TableTextOffset As Integer ' The value is determined later, at the end of the TableNonTextOffset table.

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Contains the offset location and length of the BMD header offsets.
    ''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly HeaderOffsets As New Dictionary(Of String, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer))(StringComparer.Ordinal) From {
        {"ChunkID", New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(&H0, Nothing)},
        {"Size", New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(&H4, &H5)},
        {"MagicIdentifier", New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(&H8, &HB)},
        {"EndOfTextTable", New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(&H10, &H11)},
        {"OffsetsAmount", New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(&H14, &H15)},
        {"EntriesAmount", New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(&H18, &H19)}
    } ' Friendly-Name, {Start-Offset, End-Offset}

#End Region

#Region " Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the raw byte-data of the BMD file.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property RawData As Byte()
        Get
            Return Me.rawDataB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly rawDataB As Byte()

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the Chunk ID of the file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property ChunkID As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.chunkIDB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private chunkIDB As Byte

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the size of the file.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property Size As Short
        Get
            Return Me.sizeB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private sizeB As Short

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the Magic Identifier of the file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property MagicIdentifier As Byte()
        Get
            Return Me.magicIdentifierB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private magicIdentifierB As Byte()

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the end of text table of the file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property EndOfTextTable As Short
        Get
            Return Me.endOfTextTableB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private endOfTextTableB As Short

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the amount of offsets in offset table of the file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property OffsetsAmount As Short
        Get
            Return Me.offsetsAmountB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private offsetsAmountB As Short

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the amount of entries of the file format.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property EntriesAmount As Short
        Get
            Return Me.entriesAmountB
        End Get
    End Property
    Private entriesAmountB As Short

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal filepath As String)
        Me.New(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal file As FileInfo)
        Me.New(file.FullName)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal raw As Byte())
        Me.rawDataB = raw
        Me.ReadHeader()
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Reads the BMD header.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub ReadHeader()

        Dim chunkID As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) = Me.HeaderOffsets("ChunkID")
        Dim size As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) = Me.HeaderOffsets("Size")
        Dim magicIdentifier As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) = Me.HeaderOffsets("MagicIdentifier")
        Dim endOfTextTable As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) = Me.HeaderOffsets("EndOfTextTable")
        Dim offsetsAmount As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) = Me.HeaderOffsets("OffsetsAmount")
        Dim entriesAmount As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) = Me.HeaderOffsets("EntriesAmount")

        Me.magicIdentifierB = Me.GetBytes(Me.HeaderOffset, magicIdentifier.Key, magicIdentifier.Value)
        Me.chunkIDB = Me.GetByte(Me.HeaderOffset, chunkID.Key)
        Me.sizeB = BitConverter.ToInt16(Me.GetBytes(Me.HeaderOffset, size.Key, size.Value), 0)
        Me.endOfTextTableB = BitConverter.ToInt16(Me.GetBytes(Me.HeaderOffset, endOfTextTable.Key, endOfTextTable.Value), 0)
        Me.offsetsAmountB = BitConverter.ToInt16(Me.GetBytes(Me.HeaderOffset, offsetsAmount.Key, offsetsAmount.Value), 0)
        Me.entriesAmountB = BitConverter.ToInt16(Me.GetBytes(Me.HeaderOffset, entriesAmount.Key, entriesAmount.Value), 0)

        Me.TableTextOffset = Me.TableNonTextOffset + (8 * (entriesAmountB - 1)) + 2

        Me.ReadNonTextTable()
        Me.ReadTextTable()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Reads the non-text table of the BMD file format.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' This table seems not useful.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub ReadNonTextTable()

        For x As Integer = 0 To (entriesAmountB - 1)

            Dim offset As Integer = Me.TableNonTextOffset + (8 * x)
            Dim data As Byte() = Me.GetBytes(offset, 0, 1)
            Dim value As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 0)

#If DEBUG Then
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Entry.Index.: {0}", (x + 1)))
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Start.Offset: DEC={0,-4} HEX=0x{1}", offset, offset.ToString("X")))
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Raw.Bytes...: {0}", String.Join(" ", From b As Byte In data Select b.ToString("X"))))
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Int16.Value.: {0}", value))
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Empty)
#End If

        Next

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Reads the text table of the BMD file format.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' This table contains the items identifiers and their descriptions for further translation.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub ReadTextTable()

        For x As Integer = 0 To ...
            ' ...?
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Function GetByte(ByVal start As Integer, ByVal offset As Integer) As Byte
        Return Buffer.GetByte(array:=Me.RawData, index:=start + offset)
    End Function

    Private Function GetBytes(ByVal start As Integer, ByVal from As Integer, ByVal [to] As Integer) As Byte()
        Return Me.rawDataB.Skip(start + from).Take(([to] - from) + 1).ToArray()
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

This is the C# source-code equivalent (untested) from an online .NET converter:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// Represents the BMD File Format.
/// </summary>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <remarks>
/// <see href="http://datacrystal.romhacking.net/wiki/Persona_3_and_4/BMD_%28File_Format%29"/>
/// </remarks>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public sealed class BMDFormat {

    #region " Private Fields "

    ///<summary>
    /// Specifies the offset where the header begins.
    ///</summary>
    private readonly int HeaderOffset = 0x0;

    ///<summary>
    /// Specifies the offset where the non-text table begins. This is the first table in the BMD file format.
    ///</summary>
    private readonly int TableNonTextOffset = 0x24;

    ///<summary>
    /// Specifies the offset where the text table begins. This is the second table in the BMD file format.
    ///</summary>
    private int TableTextOffset; // The value is determined later, at the end of the TableNonTextOffset table.

    ///<summary>
    /// Contains the offset location and length of the BMD header offsets.
    ///</summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, int>> HeaderOffsets = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, int>>(StringComparer.Ordinal) {
        {"ChunkID", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0x0, null)},
        {"Size", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0x4, 0x5)},
        {"MagicIdentifier", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0x8, 0xb)},
        {"EndOfTextTable", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0x10, 0x11)},
        {"OffsetsAmount", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0x14, 0x15)},
        {"EntriesAmount", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0x18, 0x19)}
    }; // Friendly-Name, {Start-Offset, End-Offset}

    #endregion

    #region " Properties "

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the raw byte-data of the BMD file.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] RawData {
        get { return this.rawDataB; }
    }
    private readonly byte[] rawDataB;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Chunk ID of the file format.
    /// </summary>
    public byte ChunkID {
        get { return this.chunkIDB; }
    }
    private byte chunkIDB;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the size of the file.
    /// </summary>
    public short Size {
        get { return this.sizeB; }
    }
    private short sizeB;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Magic Identifier of the file format.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] MagicIdentifier {
        get { return this.magicIdentifierB; }
    }
    private byte[] magicIdentifierB;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the end of text table of the file format.
    /// </summary>
    public short EndOfTextTable {
        get { return this.endOfTextTableB; }
    }
    private short endOfTextTableB;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the amount of offsets in offset table of the file format.
    /// </summary>
    public short OffsetsAmount {
        get { return this.offsetsAmountB; }
    }
    private short offsetsAmountB;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the amount of entries of the file format.
    /// </summary>
    public short EntriesAmount {
        get { return this.entriesAmountB; }
    }
    private short entriesAmountB;

    #endregion

    #region " Constructors "

    private BMDFormat() {}
    public BMDFormat(string filepath) : this(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)) {}
    public BMDFormat(FileInfo file) : this(file.FullName) {}

    public BMDFormat(byte[] raw) {
        this.rawDataB = raw;
        this.ReadHeader();
    }

    #endregion

    #region " Private Methods "

    ///<summary>
    /// Reads the BMD header.
    ///</summary>
    private void ReadHeader() {
        KeyValuePair<int, int> chunkID = this.HeaderOffsets("ChunkID");
        KeyValuePair<int, int> size = this.HeaderOffsets("Size");
        KeyValuePair<int, int> magicIdentifier = this.HeaderOffsets("MagicIdentifier");
        KeyValuePair<int, int> endOfTextTable = this.HeaderOffsets("EndOfTextTable");
        KeyValuePair<int, int> offsetsAmount = this.HeaderOffsets("OffsetsAmount");
        KeyValuePair<int, int> entriesAmount = this.HeaderOffsets("EntriesAmount");

        this.magicIdentifierB = this.GetBytes(this.HeaderOffset, magicIdentifier.Key, magicIdentifier.Value);
        this.chunkIDB = this.GetByte(this.HeaderOffset, chunkID.Key);
        this.sizeB = BitConverter.ToInt16(this.GetBytes(this.HeaderOffset, size.Key, size.Value), 0);
        this.endOfTextTableB = BitConverter.ToInt16(this.GetBytes(this.HeaderOffset, endOfTextTable.Key, endOfTextTable.Value), 0);
        this.offsetsAmountB = BitConverter.ToInt16(this.GetBytes(this.HeaderOffset, offsetsAmount.Key, offsetsAmount.Value), 0);
        this.entriesAmountB = BitConverter.ToInt16(this.GetBytes(this.HeaderOffset, entriesAmount.Key, entriesAmount.Value), 0);

        this.TableTextOffset = this.TableNonTextOffset + (8 * (entriesAmountB - 1)) + 2;

        this.ReadNonTextTable();
        this.ReadTextTable();
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Reads the non-text table of the BMD file format.
    /// <para></para>
    /// This table seems not useful.
    ///</summary>
    private void ReadNonTextTable() {
        for (int x = 0; x <= (entriesAmountB - 1); x++) {
            int offset = this.TableNonTextOffset + (8 * x);
            byte[] data = this.GetBytes(offset, 0, 1);
            short value = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 0);

            #if DEBUG
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Entry.Index.: {0}", (x + 1)));
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Start.Offset: DEC={0,-4} HEX=0x{1}", offset, offset.ToString("X")));
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Raw.Bytes...: {0}", string.Join(" ", from b in datab.ToString("X"))));
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Int16.Value.: {0}", value));
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            #endif
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Reads the text table of the BMD file format.
    /// <para></para>
    /// This table contains the items identifiers and their descriptions for further translation.
    ///</summary>
    private void ReadTextTable() {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 0; x++) {
            // ...?
        }
    }

    private byte GetByte(int start, int offset) {
        return Buffer.GetByte(array: this.RawData, index: start + offset);
    }

    private byte[] GetBytes(int start, int @from, int to) {
        return this.rawDataB.Skip(start + @from).Take((to - @from) + 1).ToArray();
    }

    #endregion

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//=======================================================
```

Comment: `because it must have a maximum length, of course.` Not necessarily.  The total length of the boots_2005 block is ~65 but the name/descr block for boots_2008 is ~87.  0x2e 0x0A follows each one which could be an end of entry signal, *or* that table after the header could be meta data describing the length of each entry

Comment: @Plutonix really thankyou for taking your time to read a big and tedious question like mine, thanks as always. `0x2e 0x0A follows each one which could be an end of entry signal` To be honest I didn't noticed that, however, maybe is not that kind of signal, because not all the blocks contains exactlly those ending bytes, the value of the first ending byte seems to be incrementing in next blocks (maybe that byte is pointing relative to something else), the second byte yes seems always to be 0x0A as you said.

Comment: `or that table after the header could be meta data describing the length of each entry` I don't think so, the amount of items/blocks in the second table are 62 (**boots_2000** to **boots_2061**), but the entries of the first table are 98. I'll be still checking.

Comment: That table starting ~0x23 seems larger than 2 or 4 bytes.  I see a pattern of 6 null bytes and then 2 bytes of data.  Decoding them shows that they do seem to increment (800,852,920,992,1056,1144).  So, it could be an index to where the boots are.  Obviously we dont know everything because there is nothing interesting at 0x320/800 and the first recognizable boots entry is at 340.  The delta of those also roughly relates to the length of each *recognizable*  block: 66,72,62 vs 65,71,65. Could just be coincidence, but seems interesting.

Comment: The problem is that we have no context and just your understanding of the format.  The boots blocks include some sort of binary data (Size? Price? Power Magnifier? Color? Whether Pixies or Elves can wear them?).  We have no idea.  It makes it hard to actually answer the question without knowing the various properties and default values etc.